Internet Archive suffered a DDOS attack and passwords may have been compromised
I know many people here rely on the Internet Archive to source books for quotes, but they have been undergoing a DDOS attack and password hashes may have been compromised. If you haven't reused the password used on that system, you'll just want to change it when they're back up, but I know a lot of people use the same password everywhere.

What we know: DDOS attack–fended off for now; defacement of our website via JS library; breach of usernames/email/salted-encrypted passwords.
What we’ve done: Disabled the JS library, scrubbing systems, upgrading security.
Will share more as we know it.

There's a bit more detail on the situation here including the detail that HaveIBeenPwned did receive a database with usernames, email addresses, and bcrypted passwords.
As a bit of an update, the Wayback Machine is back in read-only mode. Unfortunately, not all systems are reclaimed just yet, with hackers (not certain to be the same ones) answering support desk questions with messages about how the system is still compromised.
And, reportedly, other online libraries are being attacked...

Interestingly, haveibeenpwned.com doesn't list my e-mail as being exposed in that attack.  I wonder if it simply hasn't been updated yet?  Time to start using one of my zombie gmail accounts to sign up for things...

There was some speculation on the Subreddit that the hackers are overstating (or outright lying) about what they managed to do. They may have only managed to hijack the frontend. Either way, it is a reminder to not re-use passwords. Emails... are much more public generally.

If it's correctly encrypted and salted, the database is very low value.

There's a big difference between encryption and hashing. Encrypted data can be decrypted, but you can't recover a password from its hash, except by a brute-force search. And bcrypt is designed to be slow to prevent such attacks. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/326699/4014959 & https://security.stackexchange.com/q/122603

Of course, if the password is too simple, like a dictionary word, or a sequence from a list of common passwords, then a brute-force search may succeed rather quickly. But if your password is a (sufficiently long) random sequence, it should be hard to stumble across by brute-force searching.

@DavidW My account is present in haveibeenpwned.com (under IA, and Gravatar because Stack Exchange, but nowhere else). Check now?

Internet Archive is indeed mentioned on HIBP:
"Internet Archive: In September 2024, the digital library of internet sites Internet Archive suffered a data breach that exposed 31M records. The breach exposed user records including email addresses, screen names and bcrypt password hashes.
Compromised data: Email addresses, Passwords, Usernames"

After two weeks, the site is up again and appears to have full functionality.
EDIT:  Some functionality that was back when I first posted this (10/24/2024) is broken again as of this update (10/26/2024).  That's unfortunate.
FURTHER EDIT:  Since last night (10/31/2024), the site has been up and down sporadically (and it's down for me right now).  Moreover, even when it is up, many features do not appear to be working.  For example, most of the time last night I could view things that did not require a login, but I could not actually log in to check materials out.

Here is hoping... and hopefully they will build their structure more robustly. I've been following some of the chatter, and apparently some of the security holes had been there for years. :-|

It's not fully functional. I've just tried to reset my password and it's coming up with an error message. Some books are unavailable to download. I can't access a range of book archives, etc etc

For what it's worth, I was trying to use Archive.org to retrieve the image of a post on a sister site, where the post author used a third party image hosting service instead of posting directly in the answer box (because of which the image is gone).
And something strange happened: one of the archived answers' images was displaying a completely wrong image (I even went checking the answer history even though it never got edited to be sure). I have no idea if it's a bug from their part or if it has anything to do with the recent cyberattacks.
This is the original post with the correct picture: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16947/226066

And this is one of the snapshots from Archive.org with a faulty archived image (you need to block Javascript to access it, otherwise you get redirected to the original page linked above): https://web.archive.org/web/20231130173159/https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16943/screenshot-of-the-week-103

Instead of displaying the video game screenshot as originally posted, it's displaying what seems to be a picture or an advertisement for something called "Bolivia al Extremo".
Out of the 7 snapshots available for that page, 5 had the same issue, 1 didn't archive that answer, and the last one archived everything properly.
This is the first time I see something like this happen while using Archive.org.

I tried sending a message directly to Archive.org about it just in case, although I mentioned I have no idea if it has any connection to what happened recently.

Oof. Yeah, I've heard they're still having some growing pains. The ability to post link HTML in the comments apparently got reintroduced, which has led to a large number of links claiming to be for downloads, but actually routing people to malware.
